# Multilabel classification and regression on time-series data

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, lstm, multilabel

I am trying to develop an LSTM network on a vehicle dataset I have obtained from my professor. The dataset in about vehicle driving in a roundabout. I have the following tasks to complete 1. Classify which exit the vehicle is going to opt (4 classes) 2. classify the vehicle - class (5 classes) 3. forecast the position of the vehicle 1s, 3s and 5s in advance.

Right now, I have developed 3 different networks to perform all the individual tasks. I would like to know if it is possible to train a single network to fulfil all the 3 tasks mentioned above. Any recommendations and suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Sharan, and welcome to CV. The question is rather pertinent for both CV and Data Science SE, but please do not duplicate questions over the two pages, so please close one of the two if you can.

Comment: Hey @DavideND, I opted to close down the one from Data Science SE.